# How to link bootstrap to angular project manually?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, angular5

I'm building an angular 5 project on a private domain. However, I can't use `npm-install`, so I could not use it to install bootstrap. I have a bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js files on my project, but I don't know how to link them that bootstrap will works on all my project files? (Including all component and future component that will be create). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is simple way to do this like in this link:

https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/using-bootstrap-with-angular-c83c3cee3f4a

You were on the right path by downloading those file you just need a bit more.At first,to use bootstrap Jquery is required too so you need to first go and download both of the files with these links if you haven't:

- http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/
- https://code.jquery.com/

then you will need to open your index html page or a shared layout page and import the bootstrap css with `<link>` and import both the jquery and boostrap javascript with `<script>`

Comment: Great. Thank you very much!